# Blister Prevention/ Heel hardening

Tags: hiking, prevention, blisters, thru-hike

I work in the outdoor industry and I had never had any issues with blisters whilst hiking for years. 
Then one weekend I wore a pair of high heels out for a wedding and got blisters on my heels. Now I find I just cant stop getting blisters there.

Ive tried all different type of socks, I take many pairs on my hikes, I let my feet dry as soon as i get to camp, i use moleskin and similar substances as soon as i get a hot spot, i walk around barefoot as much as i can. Its just really starting to annoy me now.

Any suggestions to harden up my heels would be fantactic, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if your feet are going to harden, then they're going to harden. Chances are you just don't get out as often as you used to. I used to have massive calluses on my heels, but I simply don't put the same milage on my feet as I used to.

Now I use hikers wool, it's amazing. I have massive heel spurs so heel lift has always been a problem for me. But since being introduced to hikers wool I haven't had a single blister. My wife and I call it sheep fluff, all you do is put a pinch of fluff into your sock wherever you tend to get blisters and the fibers work into the material and somehow create a frictionless layer. It's better than moleskin, easier to use, unoticeable while you hike, and you can reuse it.